# How to replicate rows by generating months in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with customer details 
Table Customer:

```
CID CNAME
1    Abc
2    Def
3    Ghi
```

i want to add a month column to this table and replicate all the rows for every month in a select statement. months have to be generate based on current date.

Intended Output

```
Month      CID CNAME
2019-01-01 1    Abc
2019-01-01 2    Def
2019-01-01 3    Ghi
2019-02-01 1    Abc
2019-02-01 2    Def
2019-02-01 3    Ghi
2019-03-01 1    Abc
2019-03-01 2    Def
2019-03-01 3    Ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `generate_series()`.  I would do this as:

```
select gs.month, t.*
from t cross join
     generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2019-03-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(month)
order by gs.month, t.cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer my question

```
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2)) as "month",
    company_id,
    company_name
    FROM 
    company;
```

Instead of using a cross join we can do it inline.